# how to write if condition inside where condition based on subquery in yii2 query builder

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I have a subquery inside main query as below:

```
$subquery = (new Query())->select('COUNT(project_sup_id)')
    ->from('project_supervisors AS sup')
    ->where(['AND','sup.project_ref_id = p.project_id']);

$uQuery =(new Query())->select(['project_id','supcount' => $subquery])
    ->from('projects AS p')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','project_supervisors AS sup','sup.project_ref_id = project_id')
    ->andWhere('IF(supcount>0, sup_project_status=1, project_status=1)');
```

I am trying to write where condition based on logic,i.e, if the count obtained from subquery is greater than zero then where condition must be `sup_project_status=1` else `project_status=1`. In normal Mysql it is easy to write if condition inside where, but in yii2 I am not understanding how to write.

Comment: Can u provide me your sql query so can convert in yii query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use yii\db\Expression for RDBMS-native expressions:

```
->andWhere(new yii\db\Expression('IF(supcount>0, sup_project_status=1, project_status=1)'));
```

You can check your SQL using:

```
echo $uQuery->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

It returns prepared SQL command by Query object. Also you can write whole SQL as yii\db\Command:

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT count(...) FROM ... WHERE ...')->queryScalar();
```

Comment: I am getting Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'supcount' in 'where clause' if I write ->andWhere(new yii\db\Expression('IF(supcount>0, sup_project_status=1, project_status=1)'));

Comment: Something wrong with column alias. Print query using `echo $uQuery->createCommand()->getRawSql();`. You'l see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes. I got it. I found a solution with getRawSql(). Thank you